# Compiler fails to catch variable redefinition in conditional block

Tags: c, objective-c, gcc, compiler-construction, llvm

```
int bar = 2;
if (bar)
{
   int bar;
}
```

Neither gcc or Clang manages to issue a warning (or error) for this, and the program crashes immediately on launch. Is there a good reason for this? It doesn't seem like it would be something hard to catch. It's the basics of block scoping: the nested scope inherits the names of the enclosing block...

Any explanations?

EDIT: It turns out the crash was due to using Clang. I've tested many times back and forth, and it seems certain that the combination of the variable redefinition and Clang causes the crash. However, I haven't been able to reproduce the crash in a test project, so go figure.

The problem turned out to be Objective-C related. As Jonathan Leffler points out doing ´int bar = bar´ in the inner scope initializes the variable from itself, and that's what causes the problem, when the initialization is done via an Objective-C method call.

The following shows the bug in action:

```
-(void)crasher
{
   NSNumber* bar = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
   if (bar)
   {
      NSString* bar = [self doit:bar];
   }
}

-(NSString*)doit:(NSNumber*)num
{
   NSString* str = [num stringValue];   // This line causes the crash
   return str;
}
```

Note that doing something similar in pure C does *not* produce a crash:

```
int bar = 2;
if (bar)
{
   char buff[10];
   int bar = sprintf(buff, "%d",bar);       
}
```

Comment: Your C version is not "something similar". The Objective-C version seems to work with pointers. Your C version works with `int`. Try doing it with pointers in regular C and you'll get a similar crash if you try to make any non-trivial operation through an unitialized pointer.

Comment: your Objective-C and C examples are not similar: the former involves accessing an arbitrary memory region through an unitialized pointer (`doit` gets whatever garbage address is stored within the 'inner' `bar`), the latter doesn't

Comment: It seems like you both take "similar" to mean "identical". The point of comparing two things is that they are *not* identical, but perhaps similar. In this case the close formal resemblance and the fact that the sequence of function calling and assignment is the same do, in my opinion, warrant calling the two examples "similar". Furthermore, as I said in my comment on Jonathan Leffler answer, it still puzzles me that his inner bar gets initialized to 0, whereas mine doesn't (but to garbage), using the same compiler and on the same system. Clarifications welcome.

Comment: Are ints guaranteed to be initialized to 0, but pointers not? Or is it just a system idiosyncrasy?

Comment: @Felixyz: You contra-posed the "similar" examples in the context of "this one crashes and this one not". This creates an impression that the difference ("crashes or not") is something that you perceive as strange, especially in view of the "similarity" of the examples. So, we just remarked that this "similarity" has absolutely no relation to the actual reason of the crash. The reason for the crash actually hides in the *dissimilarity* of these examples.

Comment: @Felixyz: variables with automatic storage duration are not guaranteed to be initialized to any meaningful value; on first access, the OS might zero memory to prevent leakage of information from other processes, but after that, the memory will most likely contain whatever was last stored at the address; the important thing is, as AndreyT already mentioned, that in your Objective-C example, the uninitialized variable in question is a pointer, which `doit` seems to dereference, resulting in undefined behaviour even if it where zeroed  (null pointers can't be dereferenced)

Comment: @AndreyT: But that's the reason for asking a question. The difference between you, the one giving an answer, and me, the one asking, is that you see what the crucial difference is, whereas I mostly see the similarity. So informing me that the two cases are not as similar as they seem to me is not very helpful. What I want to know is wherein the crucial difference lies. I suspect that this is a very common, perhaps the most common, strategy for learning.

Comment: @Christoph: In Objective-C, null pointers can actually be dereferenced and even sent messages to (if they're of object type), so that's why I was surprised that the int seems to be initialized to 0 (in Jonathan Leffler's example) but not the pointer variable (which was garbage, rather than 0). However, I guess I can just put it down to "undefined behavior" and system particularities.

Comment: @Felixyz: As ObjC is a superset of C, null pointers most definetely can't be dereferenced; what can be done is sending messages to ´nil´ (ie null pointers of object type), but this doesn't involve accessing the underlying struct

Comment: @Christoph: You're right. But I still wonder if it's a null pointer or not. Even executing "if (!num)" causes a crash. What does that imply? If it were null, that statement wouldn't crash, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer given by Douglas Leeder:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int xx(int foo)
{
    int bar = 2;
    if (foo > bar)
    {
        int foo = bar;
        int bar = bar;
        printf("inner: foo = %d, bar = %d\n", foo, bar);
    }
    printf("outer: foo = %d, bar = %d\n", foo, bar);
    return bar;
}
int main(void)
{
    xx(13);
    return(0);
}
```

Note that the inner bar is initialized from itself - which gives undefined behaviour.  But on MacOS X 10.6.2 (GCC 4.2.1) I get:

```
inner: foo = 2, bar = 0
outer: foo = 13, bar = 2
```

---

#### Variant 1: Stack trampling - A

Interestingly, I get the same output from this code, with a stack trampling function, regardless of whether I declare `i` before or after `a`.

```
inner: foo = 2, bar = 20
outer: foo = 13, bar = 2
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void modify_stack(void)
{
    int a[20];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF ^ i;
        printf("a[i] = 0x%08X\n", a[i]);
    }
}
static int xx(int foo)
{
    int bar = 2;
    if (foo > bar)
    {
        int foo = bar;
        int bar = bar;
        printf("inner: foo = %d, bar = %d\n", foo, bar);
    }
    printf("outer: foo = %d, bar = %d\n", foo, bar);
    return bar;
}
int main(void)
{
    modify_stack();
    xx(13);
    return(0);
}
```

Since the behaviour is undefined, this result is fine.

#### Variant 2: Stack trampling - B

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int modify_stack(void)
{
    int a[20];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF ^ i;
        printf("a[i] = 0x%08X\n", a[i]);
    }
    i = a[13];
    return(i);
}
static int xx(int foo)
{
    int bar = 2;
    if (foo > bar)
    {
        int foo = bar;
        int bar = bar;
        printf("inner: foo = %d, bar = %d\n", foo, bar);
    }
    printf("outer: foo = %d, bar = %d\n", foo, bar);
    return bar;
}
int main(void)
{
    int i = modify_stack();
    xx(13);
    return(i & 0xFF);
}
```

Output (apart from data printed in loop):

```
inner: foo = 2, bar = -14
outer: foo = 13, bar = 2
```

Comment: It's interesting that the inner bar in your example is initialized to 0, whereas in my new example, which reproduces the bug, the inner bar (which is sent to doit:) is not. Even testing num for null value crashes.

Comment: @Felixyz - the zero is a quirk of the system I'm running on and the compiler I am using.  One of the interesting things about undefined behaviour is that it can look reasonable, especially in test cases.  I added a 'stack trampler' function that had a variable counting from 1 to less than 20 and when rerun, the inner 'bar' was initialized to 20 - a leftover from the stack trampler.  GCC reordered the array and the index to avoid overflows - I got the same result whether I put the index variable before or after the array.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing to catch here. The variable in the inner block is a completely different variable, that *hides* the variable in the outer block. This is a perfectly standard feature of the language that has been there since the beginning of times.

The crash you are experiencing has absolutely nothing to do with the code you posted. Unless you made a mistake in your code, working with the inner variable while assuming that your are working with the outer one.

Comment: See edit. The crash was due to initialization from the same variable, done with an Objective-C message send. However, also see the bit about Clang.

Comment: @Felixyz: Wel, your original code sample did not include any "initializations from the same variable"...

Comment: You are completely right! That's the exact reason why I made an edit, to include more information. I am simply following the recommendations of the SO faq, which states: "Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question."

Answer (score 4):

It is the basic of nested scope: inside a nested scope you can shadow something declared in an outer scope.  gcc has an option to get a warning for this (-Wshadow), but it isn't activated either by -Wall nor -Wextra: the warning can appear without change in the code (an header has now a definition at global scope for an identifier used in a function).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gcc 1.c

$ gcc -Wall 1.c
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:6: warning: unused variable ‘bar’

$ cat 1.c
int main()
{
    int bar = 2;
    if (bar)
    {
        int bar;
    }
    return 0;
}

$ ./a.out ; echo $?
0
```

Compiles for me - with a warning under -Wall. And the program runs ok.

You've declared two variables, one called `bar` and the other one also called `bar`. The compiler doesn't care, as long as they're in different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

It's also a basic of block scoping that re-defining a name from an outer scope in an inner scope isn't an error -- it's normal and expected. Doing otherwise would basically get us back to the bad old days of ancient BASIC dialects that only had global variables.